# How do I detect specific emoji

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

As 2 people told to explain it i am editing.
I have a modded minecraft server with money.
I have a discord server for the Minecraft SMP
I want to make a discord bot like YouTube.
So when a player uploads a video.
Others can either **Like**,**Dislike**,**Subscribe **
I want my bot to recognise emoji.I mean:
A content creator with 50,100,200 etc will get $500,$1000,$2000 in game.
A video with 100,200,300 likes will give the player $20,$40,$80.
A dislike will subtract likes from video like **101 likes**
**1 Dislike** will be considered 100 likes

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you explain it again?

Comment: An emoji is just a character. You "recognize" it like any other character.

Comment: Are you trying to detect reactions on a message? You can view the [on_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) event to get you started, or the [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) function.

Answer (score 1):

You’re question isn’t clear. In this answer, I will do commands with events

try to do this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(""):
        await message.channel.send("like")

    if message.content.startswith(""):
        await message.channel.send("dislike")

    if message.content.startswith(""):
        await message.channel.send("subscribe")
```

Comment: Sorry for that but I want the emoji detection

Answer (score 1):

```py
print("" in "")              # Outputs True
print("" in "I like it ")    # Outputs True

print("" == "")              # Outputs True
print("" == "I like it ")    # Outputs False
```

Comment: This is OK but I want to detect the emoji for the video

Comment: If the user sends a message in Discord, just check if the emoji is in it. [What's wrong with that? I'd like to know.](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/wings/sillylovesongs.html)

Comment: @levers - questions and answers need to stay on this site. Please refrain from asking for anyone's discord ID, email address, etc.

Comment: sorry but i needed to detect